# How do I get reflex to do backtracking when generating a flex scanner?

Tags: c++, flex-lexer

I've come up with a backtracking regex that works out fine on https://regex101.com. When I compile a simple `flex`(ish) program with `reflex -u`, the expression doesn't capture the backtracking bit -- everything else works just fine.

The documentation for `reflex` indicates that it *will* allow backtracking out of the box and I can't find anything in the documentation that tells me how to allow backtracking when using `reflex` as a replacement for `flex`.

As far as I can tell from the documentation, I have to make `reflex` use `std::regex`, since that's the only engine that supports backtracking and it seems trivial to do in a regular C++ program.

(*) Regular old flex is not an option, since it doesn't support unicode classes; specifically it doesn't support recognizing uppercase letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backtracking reflex scanners require Boost in Perl mode.  Use `reflex -m=boost-perl` to switch to the Boost Perl regex engine.  See the RE/flex documentation section on POSIX versus Perl matching: https://www.genivia.com/doc/reflex/html/index.html#reflex-posix-perl.